# "Numbered Steps" (and substeps) with references

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

Is there a standard package (or a quick way) to get an enumeration of steps/substesp/... (up to three levels) with a leading letter (or short string) and the possibility of reference each item of the enumeration?

For example:

```
 S1.  bla bla
 S2.  hello world
    S2.1. aaaa
    S2.2. bbbb
         S2.2.1 cccc
         S2.2.2 ddd     
 S3.  as done in step S2.1 ...  % \ref{some_label_at_S2.1)
```

...

```
 R1.   new enumeration with another letter
    R1.1 zzzz
    R1.2 wwww 
 R2.   heeeelllllooooo
```

...

```
 Step1.  another enumeration with a short string
       Step1.1. hello world
       Step2.2. hello world
 Step2. as said in \ref{some_label_at_R1)
```

...

Comment: enumitem is a powerful package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built an environment `mylist` with the desired behaviour using the `enumitem` package: It takes an argument specifying the prefix of the respective list (this argument doesn't have to be provided again in nested calls of `mylist`) and defines the label both for printing and referencing accordingly. Using `\label` and `\ref` works the usual way without any extra effort.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{mylistenv}{enumerate}{3}
\newenvironment{mylist}[1]{%
    \setlist[mylistenv]{label=#1\arabic{mylistenvi}.,ref=#1\arabic{mylistenvi}}%
    \setlist[mylistenv,2]{label=#1\arabic{mylistenvi}.\arabic{mylistenvii}.,ref=#1\arabic{mylistenvi}.\arabic{mylistenvii}}%
    \setlist[mylistenv,3]{label=#1\arabic{mylistenvi}.\arabic{mylistenvii}.\arabic{mylistenviii}.,ref=#1\arabic{mylistenvi}.\arabic{mylistenvii}.\arabic{mylistenviii}}%
    \renewenvironment{mylist}{\begin{mylistenv}}{\end{mylistenv}}
    \begin{mylistenv}%
}{%
    \end{mylistenv}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}{S}
    \item bla bla
    \item hello world
    \begin{mylist}
        \item aaaa \label{some_label_at_S2.1}
        \item bbbb
        \begin{mylist}
            \item cccc
            \item ddd
        \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist}
    \item as done in step~\ref{some_label_at_S2.1}
\end{mylist}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{mylist}{R}
    \item new enumeration with another letter \label{some_label_at_R1}
    \begin{mylist}
        \item zzzz
        \item wwww
    \end{mylist}
    \item heeeelllllooooo
\end{mylist}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{mylist}{Step}
    \item another enumeration with a short string
    \begin{mylist}
        \item hello world
        \item hello world
    \end{mylist}
    \item as said in \ref{some_label_at_R1}
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following

```
\newcounter{ci}
\begin{list}{S.\arabic{ci}}{\usecounter{ci}}
\renewcommand{\theci}{S.\arabic{ci}}
\item\label{lbl1}   Woof woof.
  \newcounter{cii}
  \begin{list}{S.\arabic{ci}.\arabic{cii}}{\usecounter{cii}}
  \renewcommand{\thecii}{S.\arabic{ci}.\arabic{cii}}
  \item\label{lbl11}   Mew mew.
    \newcounter{ciii}
    \begin{list}{S.\arabic{ci}.\arabic{cii}.\arabic{ciii}}{\usecounter{ciii}}
    \renewcommand{\theciii}{S.\arabic{ci}.\arabic{cii}.\arabic{ciii}}
    \item   Baa baa
    \item\label{lbl112}   Moo moo.
    \end{list}
  \item   Tweet tweet.
  \end{list}
\item   Cluck cluck.
\end{list}

Woof ref: \ref{lbl1} \\
Mew ref: \ref{lbl11} \\
Moo ref: \ref{lbl112} \\

\end{document}
```

The following would also work, except for what looks like a bug in the referencing of 3rd level enumerate items:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{S.\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{S.\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{S.\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{S.\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}}

\item   bla bla

\item   hello world

  \begin{enumerate}

  \item\label{athing}   aaaa

  \item   bbbb

    \begin{enumerate}

    \item   cccc

    \item\label{thingy2}   ddd

    \end{enumerate}

  \end{enumerate}

\item   as done in step \ref{athing}

\item   in contrast to step \ref{thingy2}

\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{R.\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{R.\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{R.\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{R.\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}}

\item\label{newenum}   new enumeration with another letter

  \begin{enumerate}

  \item   zzzz

  \item   wwww

  \end{enumerate}

\item   heeeelllllooooo

\item   ...

\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{Step.\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{Step.\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{Step.\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}}

\item   another enumeration with a short string

  \begin{enumerate}

  \item   hello world

  \item   hello world

  \end{enumerate}

\item   as said in \ref{newenum}

\item   an alternative to \ref{athing}

\end{enumerate}
```